# ngx-datatable - Filter column does not work properly?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created filter for name column like documentation:

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/filter.component.ts

When type some text in input control I'm getting this good result from table, but when I delete text from input fields or start typing other text datatable needs be to refresh on first state or show new value. That doesn't work...just message "No data" and each time I have to refresh page for a new search..

**threat.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Threat } from '../../../../models/threat.model';
import { ThreatService } from '../../../../services/threat.service';
import { DatatableComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-threat',
 templateUrl: './threat.component.html',
})
export class ThreatComponent implements OnInit {
public showLoadingIcon: boolean;
private ref: ChangeDetectorRef;

threats: Threat[] = [];
temp: Threat[] = [];

@ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private threatService: ThreatService
) {
    this.ref = ref;
    this.showLoadingIcon = false;

    this.temp = this.threats;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetThreats();
}

onGetThreats() {
    this.threatService.getThreats()
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.threats = response.items;
        });
}

filterThreatName(event: any){
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const temp = this.threats.filter(function (result) {
        return result.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });

    this.threats = temp;
    this.table.offset = 0;
 }
}
```

**threat.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <div class="container">
            <div [fxFlex]="calc3cols" class="col3">
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="button-row">
                    <input 
                           style='padding:7px;margin:15px auto;width:150px;'
                           placeholder="Search name column..."
                           (keyup)='filterThreatName($event)'/>
                    <a mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/threat/new">CREATE</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <div class="container">
            <div [fxFlex]="calc3cols" class="col3">
                <ngx-datatable #table
                               [columnMode]="'force'"
                               [headerHeight]="50"
                               [footerHeight]="0"
                               [rowHeight]="50"
                               [sorts]="[{prop: 'threatId', dir: 'desc'}]"
                               [rows]="threats">
                    <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
                        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                            <a [routerLink]="['/threat/edit/', row['threatId']]">{{row['name']}}</a>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngx-datatable-column>
                    <ngx-datatable-column name="Category" prop="category.name"></ngx-datatable-column>
                </ngx-datatable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Does anyone know what's problem ?

Comment: am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the offset is not working because the offset is after you change the filter it brings you back to the first page.